# Replacing loop in a loop to find match in two vectors with STL

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

Given structure:

```cpp
struct bob
{
    int a {1};
    std::string b{"bob"};
};

std::vector<bob> list1{{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}};
std::vector<bob> list2{{1, "x"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "x"}};
```

I want to find if a match exists. The classic way to do this is a loop in loop - something like:

```cpp
    for (const auto &item1 : list1)
    {
        for (const auto &item2 : list2)
        {
            std::cout << "loop check: " << item1.a << "," << item1.b << " == "<< item2.a << "," << item2.b << "\n";
            if (item2.a == item1.a && 
                item2.b == item1.b)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

clangtidy modernisation features complains that using raw loops is not the way forward, so I have converted to an STL using `std::any_of`:

```cpp
    return std::any_of(
        list1.begin(),
        list1.end(),
        [&](const auto &item1)
        {
            return std::any_of(
                list2.begin(),
                list2.end(),
                [&](const auto &item2) {
                    std::cout << "stl check: " << item1.a << "," << item1.b << " == "<< item2.a << "," << item2.b << "\n";
                    return item2.a == item1.a &&
                           item2.b == item1.b;
                });
        });
```

But I can't help thinking this is harder to read and more code etc...

Is there a better arrangement, or different algorithm that will do this in a more clear/expressive way?

Here is the full working example: https://godbolt.org/z/e8MYYK5G4

Note: c++17 is being used

Comment: Do the matches have to be at the same place like in your example or anywhere in either container?

Comment: Perhaps [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) together with a suitable comparison function?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen anywhere in the container - so long as its an exact match

Comment: Is the output required?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ... hmm.. I am not sure I want the output set.. also doesn't the inputs need to be sorted first?

Comment: @Jarod42 - no just a bool result for this example/use-case

Comment: If you want better time complexity, sort both containers and then use `std::set_intersection`. This way you end up with O(N\*log(N) + M\*log(M)) time complixity instead of O(N * M), where N and M are the sizes of your containers.

Comment: `return std::any_of(list1.begin(), list1.end(), [&](const auto& item1){ return std::find(list2.begin(), list2.end(), item1) == list2.end(); });` (ranges version would be shorter and/or `std::contains`).

Comment: Not directly related, but which clang-tidy check asks you to get rid of a loop? All I see is [modernize-loop-convert](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize/loop-convert.html), but that's just about using range-based loops instead of index or iterator.

Comment: Without ranges, I suggest to write helper function for version with container instead of iterator. `ranges::any_of(list1, [&](const auto& elem){ return ranges::contains(list2, elem); });`.

Comment: And adding `bool bob::operator==(const bob&) const` might help to get rid of one lambda for equality in my cases.

Comment: @Jarod42 - that works, but I need `!= list2.end()` and also I need a `operator==()` function for the class - I guess I could replace that with `find_if` and use an appropriate predicate

Comment: @Jarod42 ah, sorry I just spotted your next comments! - since I don't have ranges, I think a mix of your original is nice, plus find_if

Comment: oh wait...no, then I just end up more or less back where I started :p

Comment: @Yksisarvinen sorry wrong clang-tidy item, it was `useStlAlgorithm`

Comment: I don't see how you can use `std::set_intersection` here. If you provide `operator<` the ordering will be weak, thus several element will satisfy `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` although they are different. The `set_intersection` will output equivalent elements according to this weak ordering which is not what OP wants.

Comment: @Dorian: "the ordering will be weak". why? With `return std::tie(lhs.a, lhs.b) < std::tie(rhs.a, rhs.b)` equivalent item **are** equal.

Comment: @Dorian -- The OP's structure is basically equivalent to `std::pair<int, std::string>`, which is sortable right out-of-the-box.  Are you saying that `std::pair` will not work also?

Comment: I don't think it will, imagine the two pairs `a = {1, "foo"}, b = {2, "ba"}` if you use a member wise comparison, you will have `a < b == false` (cause "foo" > "ba") and `b < a == false` (because 2 > 1). Thus a and b will be treated as equivalent. See the possible [implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection#Version_1)

Comment: @code_fodder -- What are the real-world sizes of those vectors?  10 elements? 100 elements?  Thousands?  If the amounts are large, then there is no disadvantage in sorting the larger vector first, and then using `std::lower_bound` in a loop on the smaller vector, which would do a binary search into the larger, sorted vector.

Comment: @Dorian: comparing pairs/tuples (and therefor `std::tie`) does lexical comparison, so for your example, a<b == true. The first element takes priority, and the second is considered only if the first elements compare equal.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie more then 10, less then 100. So its not really an optimisation task  - I would say readability and maintainability are more important (IMO)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start by defining comparison for `struct bob`, so the rest of the code doesn't need to deal with its internal details. If you're using C++20 or newer, you can use the spaceship operator to do that. Otherwise, you can define `operator<` instead.

```cpp
struct bob {
    // existing contents of bob ...

    // C++20 or newer:
    // auto operator<=>(bob const &) const = default;

    // C++17 or older:
    bool operator<(bob const &other) const {
        if (a == other.a) return b < other.b;
        return a < other.a;
    }
};
```

Then we want to determine whether any element of one collection is contained in the other collection. Like @chrysante, I'd sort and then search. But I'd use a binary search instead of a linear search.

The standard library actually contains three different function templates for doing binary searching. Most of the time, we want `upper_bound` or `lower_bound`--either will try to find a specific location of an element in a collection. But in this case, we don't care about a specific location--we just need a Boolean result to tell us whether it's there or not. Fortunately for us, that's exactly what `std::binary_search` does.

```cpp
template <class T, class U>
bool intersects(T const &a, U b) {
    std::sort(std::begin(b), std::end(b));

    return std::any_of(std::begin(a), std::end(a),
        [&](auto const &x) { return std::binary_search(std::begin(b), std::end(b), x); });
}
```

For the moment I've defined only a single version that sorts a copy of one inputs. If you can modify the original, pass `b` by reference instead.

Depending on the sizes of the collections, and the expected number of intersecting elements, this may not be the most efficient way to do things though. `std::set_intersection` requires that we sort both inputs, then traverses the two in parallel to find intersecting items. The algorithm above has complexity O(M log N) where M and N are the sizes of the two collections.

`std::set_intersection` has complexity O(M + N), but also continues searching, to find all elements that match between the two collections. So exactly which will be faster in any given situation is somewhat difficult to pin down.

Once we have those, let's try a couple of tests--one that should produce a positive result, the other a negative:

```cpp
int main() { 
    std::vector<bob> list1{{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}};
    std::vector<bob> list2{{1, "x"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "x"}};
    std::vector<bob> list3{{1, "I don't think so"}, {5, "nope"}, { 17, "no way"}};

    std::cout << "1 and 2 intersect? " << std::boolalpha << intersects(list1, list2) << "\n";
    std::cout << "2 and 3 intersect? " << std::boolalpha << intersects(list2, list3) << "\n";

}
```

At least for me, this produces what I'd expect:

```cpp
1 and 2 intersect? true
2 and 3 intersect? false
```

[<kbd>Live on Godbolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/7ccxPvz1W)

Comment: I guess in this case you would not need to sort `a`.

Comment: @chrysante: true.

Comment: Looks very neat though :-)

Comment: No longer need to take `a` by copy so.

Comment: Creating an `std::unordered_map` for `b` would be possible alternatively ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 Great idea, then you actually end up with linear time complexity

Comment: @Jarod42: I believe `std::unordered_set` would suffice, but yes that would work too. Probably won't get any improvement for sets of three items, but if the collections are large enough it would eventually be (quite) significant. Then again, for three items, sorting and binary search is overkill too... Given that the original was O(NM) and modified only in response to clangtidy, not performance problems, I doubt the collections involved are very large, but it's hard to be sure.

Comment: I guess the major take-away here is providing a comparison operator can make life much easier! - thanks and open possibility of  using other tools

Answer (score 1):

I know this does not answer your question about clang-tidy, but for better runtime performance consider doing this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <optional>
#include <tuple>

std::optional<bob> find_match_mutating(std::vector<bob>& a, std::vector<bob>& b) {
    auto less = [](auto& a, auto& b) {
        return std::tie(a.a, a.b) < std::tie(b.a, b.b);
    }; 
    auto equal = [](auto& a, auto& b) {
        return std::tie(a.a, a.b) == std::tie(b.a, b.b);
    }; 
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), less);
    std::sort(b.begin(), b.end(), less);
    auto itr = std::find_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [&, j = b.begin()](bob const& aBob) mutable {
        j = std::lower_bound(j, b.end(), aBob, less);
        return j < b.end() && equal(*j, aBob);
    });
    if (itr != a.end()) {
        return *itr;
    }
    return std::nullopt;
}

// Or if you don't want to mutate the original ranges
std::optional<bob> find_match(std::vector<bob> a, std::vector<bob> b) {
    return find_match_mutating(a, b);
}
```

This way you end up with O(N*log(N) + M*log(M)) time complixity instead of O(N*M), where N and M are the sizes `a` and `b` respectively.

If you want the position of the element in the original ranges, do a linear search for them. You still end up with N*log(N) time complexity.

For sufficiently large ranges this will guaranteed be faster than your original O(N*M) solution. For small ranges however other factors could dominate the execution time. In this case you would have to measure.

Comment: If both `a` and `b` are sorted, you could use `std::lower_bound/std::upper_bound` instead of the `find_if` loop.

Comment: Once sorted [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) might be used.

Comment: @Jarod42 But `std::set_intersection` outputs the _entire_ set intersection, but we only care about one matching element. @PaulMcKenzie thanks for the suggestion on `std::lower_bound`.

Comment: I don't think `set_intersection` can work, see my comments on the question.

Comment: @chrysante: Using the algo, you have a linear pass. else a custom output iterator (as a count_iterator) might do the job. Not shorter than OP's code though ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 I guess you can make it work, it just seems a bit overkill. But you're right, it doesn't make the time complexity worse.

Comment: You do not achieve the time  complexity you promised. Also, OP wanted c++17.

Comment: @Eugene Why would it not be O(N\*log(N))?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I need it because `j = std::lower_bound(j, b.end(), aBob, less);`always reduces the range that `lower_bound` searches. Otherwise I would have to give the entire range `b` to `lower_bound` in every iteration of the `find_if` loop. Then I end up with O(N\*log(M)) time complexity in that part. I guess you would explicitly have to count operations to see which is less.

Comment: Now after your edit it will be the right complexity.

Comment: With similar [set_intersection algo](https://godbolt.org/z/95f84Mzvs).

Comment: @Eugene even before (with double `std::find_if` loop) it was the right complexity. The inner `find_if` loop always decreased the searched range so in total it would be traversed only once.

Comment: @Jarod42 this looks great, but I thought the objective is to do it only with STL-algorithms :-D

Comment: @chrysante actually the objective was to make the code more expressive / easy to read / maintain. Whereas I think this answer is probably leaning to, very clever highly optimised, but much harder to understand code (for the more average programmer). But I am learning a lot from this - and your answer def deserves +1'ing